# Use CMD or Terminal from Eclipse plug-in programmatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, terminal, cmd

I need to send commands to the windows CMD or linux terminal from an Eclipse wizard. Not my first choice but I'm not the architect so just following orders. Is there a way to send a command to the CMD and/or Terminal?

For an example, we'll be doing:

```
mvn -create $projectName $location
```

where we replace the project name and location with values from the wizard. Yes I know there is an mvn plug-in, I have a specific reason for needing this (or at least my boss does). Suggestions?

Also, I do NOT need a plug-in that allows you to type to the CMD or Terminal from Eclipse. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do this in a separate thread - e.g. a new `Job` - then you can just use the existing `java.lang.Runtime.exec(...)` mechanism...

If you want to follow the execution as well in a console within IDE, then have a look at `org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.views.console.ProcessConsole` or one of its super-classes.

Comment: Never heard of either of these but it sounds perfect for what I need. thanks